# Mount data volume, then create symbolic link at container creation in docker

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

When docker-compose creates the container, is it possible to create a symbolic link from volume-mounted directory to another location in container?

I know it can be done in the Dockerfile, but I wont have the data volume mounted at the moment of building the image.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link to a file or directory that doesn't exist. And you can also mount a volume over top of an existing file/directory and the symbolic link will point to the newly mounted contents. So add the link inside your Dockerfile to the image.